# CloseMainWindow not work in invoke-command

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I want to stop a winform application on remote from local powershell script, but `CloseMainWindow` function seem not work

---This is local command to connect remote server to execute closeApp.ps1 which is stored on server--

```
$remoteSession = New-PSSession -computerName 'xxx' -credential $cred  
Invoke-Command -session $remoteSession -command {F:\AutoDeployment\closeApp.ps1}  
Remove-pSSession -session $remoteSession
```

---This is main content of closeApp.ps1 which get active process and try to close it--

```
$app = Get-Process AppName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
if($app)  
{  
  $app.MainWindowTitle  
  $app.CloseMainWindow()  
}
```

I expect it should be act as local did which shall close app properly.

But now it returns null for `mainWindowTitle` line and False for `closeMainWindow`.
This script works fine if directly run on server, but when it comes to be execute through `invoke-command`, `MainWindow` seem to be invalid and not work .

I'm calling this command through jenkins plugin powershell

> Updates:

There's no error log through `invoke-command` for `closeMainWindow` but it always return 'False' which expected to be 'True'.

What's more I have a further step that will try to send key actions to make that app stop if `closeMainWindow` failed. I use `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait` to achieve that.
It also works in local but fails through `invoke-command` on server with log:

error log for `sendkeys`:

`Exception calling "SendWait" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Exception calli...cess is denied":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figure out why this issue happened now and hope that will helps anyone.

Windows just prevent any remote actions to invoke an interactive process(as far as I know), so each time I'm trying to start-process through `invoke-command` in remote computer, it just starts up a 'ghost' process and it's invisible. So I think that's why I can't use `closeMainWindow` function properly because it is UI related.

My purpose is to do something(send keys) to a visible program on remote for auto deployment, so I find the only way is to use `schtasks` to schedule actions on remote and let remote do UI part itself.That works fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that assemblies for Winforms are not loaded during a remote call and as a result you don't have the CloseMainWindow function available to you. Try to load the assemblies explicitly as in:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
```

Since you haven't supplied enough information about error codes, you can try the below to rule out an execution policy restriction by bypassing it for that run:

```
$remoteSession = New-PSSession -computerName 'xxx' -credential $cred

Invoke-Command -session $remoteSession -command {powershell.exe -execution Bypass -file 'F:\AutoDeployment\closeApp.ps1'}

Remove-pSSession -session $remoteSession
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but actually `closeMainWindow` is a function of Process class instead of Forms, though I have add assembly load in my scripts for 'System.Windows.Forms' and 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' for further use, but it still return False on `closeMainWindow`